# R+arrow: Error when using the dataset API

Tags: r, csv, apache-arrow

Please have a look at the snippet at the end of the file.
I am making my first baby steps with arrow and R to deal with files which are too large to be loaded in memory.

I am trying to reproduce the steps here

https://francoismichonneau.net/2022/10/import-big-csv/

which illustrates how to convert a large tsv file to a parquet file without loading it into memory.
I know it is bad practice to use a link pointing to your data, but I have no alternative to provide a minimal example which nevertheless fails.

You can download the test.tsv file (a small extract of a much larger file) here

https://mega.nz/file/V9FnhazJ#YXBvpuRVQ9s3nVkWCQEaWn0g9Ul6pmtXlap6X7Zkz1E

In the reprex I have some errors but I do not understand where they come from and they do not appear compatible with the data. Any help is much appreciated!

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(arrow)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'arrow'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
#> 
#>     timestamp


data1<- read_tsv("test.tsv") ## data in memory
#> Rows: 10000 Columns: 29
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: "\t"
#> chr (27): AID_MEASURE_ID, DATE_CREATED, DATE_GRANTED, AA_PUBLISHED_DATE, SER...
#> dbl  (2): GRANTED_AMOUNT_FROM_EUR, NOMINAL_AMOUNT_EUR_FROM
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

data1
#> # A tibble: 10,000 × 29
#>    AID_MEASURE_ID DATE_…¹ DATE_…² AA_PU…³ SERVE…⁴ AM_TI…⁵ AM_TI…⁶ STATUS AM_PR…⁷
#>    <chr>          <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  
#>  1 SA.41416       24/11/… 18/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  2 SA.41416       24/11/… 18/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  3 SA.41416       24/11/… 18/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  4 SA.41416       24/11/… 18/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  5 SA.41416       25/11/… 25/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  6 SA.41416       25/11/… 29/08/… 09/12/… TM-100… NGA Sc… NGA Sc… Publi… N      
#>  7 SA.45235       02/11/… 27/10/… 02/11/… TM-100… 2014–2… Measur… Publi… X      
#>  8 SA.45235       02/11/… 27/10/… 02/11/… TM-100… 2014–2… Measur… Publi… X      
#>  9 SA.33193       08/11/… 27/10/… 11/01/… TM-100… R&D&I-… R & D … Publi… N      
#> 10 SA.42321       16/11/… 01/11/… 01/06/… TM-100… POTENC… POTENT… Publi… X      
#> # … with 9,990 more rows, 20 more variables: COFINANCE <chr>, OBJECTIVE <chr>,
#> #   OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN <chr>, AID_INSTRUMENT <chr>,
#> #   OTHER_AID_INSTRUMENT_EN <chr>, BENEFICIARY_NAME <chr>,
#> #   BENEFICIARY_NAME_ENGLISH <chr>, BENEFICIARY_NATIONAL_ID <chr>,
#> #   BENEFICIARY_NAT_ID_TYPE_SD <chr>, BENEFICIARY_TYPE_SD <chr>,
#> #   COUNTRY_SD <chr>, REGION_SD <chr>, SECTOR_SD <chr>,
#> #   GRANTED_AMOUNT_FROM_EUR <dbl>, NOMINAL_AMOUNT_EUR_FROM <dbl>, …
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names

data2 <- open_dataset("test.tsv", format="tsv")

data2
#> FileSystemDataset with 1 csv file
#> AID_MEASURE_ID: string
#> DATE_CREATED: string
#> DATE_GRANTED: string
#> AA_PUBLISHED_DATE: string
#> SERVER_REF: string
#> AM_TITLE: string
#> AM_TITLE_EN: string
#> STATUS: string
#> AM_PROC_TYPE_CD: string
#> COFINANCE: string
#> OBJECTIVE: string
#> OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN: null
#> AID_INSTRUMENT: string
#> OTHER_AID_INSTRUMENT_EN: string
#> BENEFICIARY_NAME: string
#> BENEFICIARY_NAME_ENGLISH: string
#> BENEFICIARY_NATIONAL_ID: string
#> BENEFICIARY_NAT_ID_TYPE_SD: string
#> BENEFICIARY_TYPE_SD: string
#> COUNTRY_SD: string
#> REGION_SD: string
#> SECTOR_SD: string
#> GRANTED_AMOUNT_FROM_EUR: double
#> NOMINAL_AMOUNT_EUR_FROM: double
#> GRANT_RANGE: string
#> GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME: string
#> GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME_EN: string
#> NUTS_CD: string
#> GRANTING_AUTHORITY_COUNTRY: string

data3 <- read_tsv_arrow("test.tsv",as_data_frame=F)



##This works

write_dataset(
  data3,
  format = "parquet",
  path = ".",
  max_rows_per_file = 1e7
)

print("Done with the first parquet file")
#> [1] "Done with the first parquet file"


## but this does not...why?

write_dataset(
  data2,
  format = "parquet",
  path = ".",
  max_rows_per_file = 1e7
)
#> Error: Invalid: In CSV column #11: Row #9107: CSV conversion error to null: invalid value 'SECURITY ARRANGEMENTS'


###Apparently there is an error with the string "Security Arrangements" on line
### 9107. Let us see

data_error <- data1[9107, ] |>
    glimpse()
#> Rows: 1
#> Columns: 29
#> $ AID_MEASURE_ID             <chr> "SA.33193"
#> $ DATE_CREATED               <chr> "27/09/17"
#> $ DATE_GRANTED               <chr> "14/09/17"
#> $ AA_PUBLISHED_DATE          <chr> "27/09/17"
#> $ SERVER_REF                 <chr> "TM-10080819"
#> $ AM_TITLE                   <chr> "R&D&I-scheme Flanders. Prolongation of an …
#> $ AM_TITLE_EN                <chr> "R & D & I-scheme Flanders. Extension of an…
#> $ STATUS                     <chr> "Published"
#> $ AM_PROC_TYPE_CD            <chr> "N"
#> $ COFINANCE                  <chr> "No"
#> $ OBJECTIVE                  <chr> "Research and development"
#> $ OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN         <chr> NA
#> $ AID_INSTRUMENT             <chr> "Direct grant"
#> $ OTHER_AID_INSTRUMENT_EN    <chr> NA
#> $ BENEFICIARY_NAME           <chr> "INDAVER"
#> $ BENEFICIARY_NAME_ENGLISH   <chr> "INDAVER"
#> $ BENEFICIARY_NATIONAL_ID    <chr> "0427.973.304"
#> $ BENEFICIARY_NAT_ID_TYPE_SD <chr> "KBO/BCE"
#> $ BENEFICIARY_TYPE_SD        <chr> "Only large enterprises"
#> $ COUNTRY_SD                 <chr> "Belgium"
#> $ REGION_SD                  <chr> NA
#> $ SECTOR_SD                  <chr> "E.38.21-Treatment and disposal of non-haza…
#> $ GRANTED_AMOUNT_FROM_EUR    <dbl> 644531
#> $ NOMINAL_AMOUNT_EUR_FROM    <dbl> NA
#> $ GRANT_RANGE                <chr> "Not Range"
#> $ GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME    <chr> "VLAIO"
#> $ GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME_EN <chr> "VLAIO"
#> $ NUTS_CD                    <chr> NA
#> $ GRANTING_AUTHORITY_COUNTRY <chr> "Belgium"


### but I see nothing about that text on that line

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] arrow_9.0.0.2   forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.9    
#>  [5] purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0     tibble_3.1.8   
#>  [9] ggplot2_3.3.6   tidyverse_1.3.1
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] lubridate_1.8.0   assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.29     utf8_1.2.2       
#>  [5] R6_2.5.1          cellranger_1.1.0  backports_1.4.1   reprex_2.0.1     
#>  [9] evaluate_0.15     httr_1.4.3        highr_0.9         pillar_1.8.0     
#> [13] rlang_1.0.4       readxl_1.4.0      R.utils_2.12.0    R.oo_1.25.0      
#> [17] rmarkdown_2.14    styler_1.7.0      bit_4.0.4         munsell_0.5.0    
#> [21] broom_1.0.0       compiler_4.2.1    modelr_0.1.8      xfun_0.31        
#> [25] pkgconfig_2.0.3   htmltools_0.5.2   tidyselect_1.1.2  fansi_1.0.3      
#> [29] crayon_1.5.1      tzdb_0.3.0        dbplyr_2.2.0      withr_2.5.0      
#> [33] R.methodsS3_1.8.2 grid_4.2.1        jsonlite_1.8.0    gtable_0.3.0     
#> [37] lifecycle_1.0.1   DBI_1.1.3         magrittr_2.0.3    scales_1.2.0     
#> [41] vroom_1.5.7       cli_3.3.0         stringi_1.7.8     fs_1.5.2         
#> [45] xml2_1.3.3        ellipsis_0.3.2    generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.4.1      
#> [49] tools_4.2.1       bit64_4.0.5       R.cache_0.16.0    glue_1.6.2       
#> [53] hms_1.1.1         parallel_4.2.1    fastmap_1.1.0     yaml_2.3.5       
#> [57] colorspace_2.0-3  rvest_1.0.2       knitr_1.39        haven_2.5.0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you import data without specifying the data types (the schema), they are being inferred from your file. `read_tsv_arrow()` and `open_dataset()` use different strategies to do so:

- `read_tsv_arrow()` does it by looking at the full dataset
- `open_dataset()` does it by scanning the first few rows of the dataset

The error message you get tells you that the parser cannot convert to `null` something that looks like text.

The schema reported by `open_dataset()` tells you that the only column with the `null` type is `OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN`. If you look at the schema reported by `read_tsv_arrow()`, you will see that the `OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN` is a `string`. This difference points you to what the error message suggests. There is actually text data in that column but it is further down from what the parser looks at to infer the data types. You cannot rely on the default behavior of `open_dataset()` in your case and you need to specify the schema manually:

```
data <- open_dataset("test.tsv",
  format = "tsv",
  skip_rows = 1, 
  schema = schema(
    AID_MEASURE_ID = string(), 
    DATE_CREATED = string(), 
    DATE_GRANTED = string(), 
    AA_PUBLISHED_DATE = string(), 
    SERVER_REF = string(), 
    AM_TITLE = string(), 
    AM_TITLE_EN = string(), 
    STATUS = string(), 
    AM_PROC_TYPE_CD = string(), 
    COFINANCE = string(), 
    OBJECTIVE = string(), 
    OTHER_OBJECTIVE_EN = string(), 
    AID_INSTRUMENT = string(), 
    OTHER_AID_INSTRUMENT_EN = string(), 
    BENEFICIARY_NAME = string(), 
    BENEFICIARY_NAME_ENGLISH = string(), 
    BENEFICIARY_NATIONAL_ID = string(), 
    BENEFICIARY_NAT_ID_TYPE_SD = string(), 
    BENEFICIARY_TYPE_SD = string(), 
    COUNTRY_SD = string(), 
    REGION_SD = string(), 
    SECTOR_SD = string(), 
    GRANTED_AMOUNT_FROM_EUR = double(), 
    NOMINAL_AMOUNT_EUR_FROM = double(), 
    GRANT_RANGE = string(), 
    GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME = string(), 
    GRANTING_AUTHORITY_NAME_EN = string(), 
    NUTS_CD = string(), 
    GRANTING_AUTHORITY_COUNTRY = string()
  )
)

write_dataset(
  data,
  format = "parquet",
  path = ".",
  max_rows_per_file = 1e7
)
```

Note that when specifying the schema with `open_dataset()` you need to skip the first row which contains the column names.

In the error message, the row number with the incorrect data type is off by one because the header is included in the count.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had overlooked the scheme part and I did not know the header was included in the count. Now I can use the power of arrow on my large dataset without running out of memory.

Comment: Just  a question: I noticed that you use "skip_rows = 1". Is it something I am supposed to do every time the tsv (or text file) has a header? Would I need to do the same also if the data were stored as a parquet file? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to use `skip_rows = 1` if you specify a schema or the column names by hand for text files.